Adapt search layer function in qgis2web
I want to add in my interactive map created in openlayer with the latest version of qgis2web a search layer that allows the user to search for any attribute of any of the layers on the map.
Is there any way to add a search layer that allows the user to search any layers and fields and not only a specific one? I leave the code as example where I can only filter elements of the Reg_ENTRERIOS layer and only if the user searches it by 'Fid'.
    var searchLayer = new SearchLayer({
    layer: lyr_01_REG_ENTRERIOS_01_2,
    colName: 'fid',
    zoom: 10,
    collapsed: true,
    map: map
});

I had modified the qgis2web.js file adding in "layer:" the list of all the layers that I have in my project and in "colName" the name of all the fields that I have, but I wanted to consult if there is not a more practical and less tedious way to do it.

Unfortunately I do not have an answer for qgis2web. But I can give you a tip: With qgis2o.gis (export as openlayers) and the function “quick search” it is possible. It is not a free plugin, but it is excellent.
